# I need help removing a lot of materials.

Tags: materials

So I have this model I created, but I created over 7000 materials and I only use about 10 out of the 7000. Is there anyway I can get rid of all the 7000 unused material. I already tried the orphan cleanup addon, but it didn't remove any of the materials.

Comment: Clearing orphan data should do exactly what you want. Can you provide some detailed steps you tried? WIth screenshots of the orphan data tabs?

Comment: Never mind, I managed to fix the issue. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Post an answer to your own question please, future users may have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree, Leander, I am interested in how to clear orphan data, the term new to me. Also, I'm interested in the addon. I just bookmarked this page.